# Email campaign / newsletter with store products

Tags: newsletter

I'm trying to find the best method to send out a weekly newsletter / email campaign that includes about a dozen selected products.

I've read several different methods that integrate with 3rd party websites, however I'm a little hesitant to go this route and would prefer to achieve this using the default newsletter feature.

What is the recommended method to include products on the newsletter for an email marketing campaign?

Comment: use mailchimp plugin

Comment: I looked into it, I don't like that they hold all the email addresses. It also gives the impression to my mailing list that I've signed them up for spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply wanting to add a link to the product into the newsletter then you can add a new newsletter template, then insert into this template using the cms widget "Catalog Product Link" you can add a link to a product. This is the same as adding a link to a product via a cms page or block.

If you are looking at sending a product list then I would suggest looking into how the widget "Catalog New Products List" works. You could extend this to take a list of product ids that need to be included in your list.

A nice example is the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random` here is just makes a list of products randomly but you could add a products ids attribute and then create your own `_getProductCollection`

Answer (score 0):

I agree to use the Mailchimp plugin. Before you start sending the newsletter, you should ideally determine, which products each subscriber is most likely to buy and include specific product recommendations into the email. It drives much better conversions. Such personalization is a "Mission Impossible" to be done manually, but a piece of cake for tools like Futurelytics. It will even create a ready-made email template for your newsletter in Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

[Sender plugin](https://marketplace.magento.com/sendernet-synergia-sendercommerce.html) have these features. You can use this tool to send weekly emails automatically and integrate your products with own emails design. For different products I recommend use segmentation function, this will improve subscribers engagement. Sender plugin is free, here's information about features: https://www.sender.net/features/